# How would I pull out similar value pairs from a dictionary and put them in a new dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary filled with 3 keys: `"Ticker"`, `"Title"` and `"Value"`. The ticker key contains 100 stock tickers that corresponds to the value of the purchase and title that are in the same position. So here is an example of the dictionary:

```py
{'Ticker': {0: 'AKUS', 1: 'HHC', 2: 'IOVA', 3: 'DDOG'},
 'Title': {0: '10%', 1: 'Dir, 10%', 2: 'Dir', 3: 'Dir'},
 'Value': {0: '+$374,908,350', 1: '+$109,214,243', 2: '+$65,000,000', 3: '+$49,999,940'}}
```

So `"AKUS"` corresponds with the 10% and +$374,908,350.

I am only showing 4 items in the dictionary but my actual dictionary has 100.

My question is regarding a new dictionary that only contains tickers and values but everything in that dictionary has the same title.

For example, I want to create a 10% dictionary that contains all the tickers and values of stocks where the title contained 10%.

I know some stocks have multiple titles but I don't mind the same stocks being in more than one dictionary. Would some one be able to let me know how I should go about doing this? Thank you in advance, I have been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple to do using pandas if you are OK using that; so assuming your dictionary is named d:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df10 = df[df['Title'].str.contains('10%')]
print(df10)
```

produces

```
  Ticker     Title          Value
0   AKUS       10%  +$374,908,350
1    HHC  Dir, 10%  +$109,214,243
```

Answer (score 1):

As you only want to get the `"Ticker"` and `"Value"` values that have a `"Title"` that contains `"10%"` in its value, you need to filter both `"Ticker"` and `"Value"` against that. You can do it verbose or using dictionary comprehension:

```py
stocks = {'Ticker': {0: 'AKUS', 1: 'HHC', 2: 'IOVA', 3: 'DDOG'},
          'Title': {0: '10%', 1: 'Dir, 10%', 2: 'Dir', 3: 'Dir'},
          'Value': {0: '+$374,908,350', 1: '+$109,214,243', 2: '+$65,000,000', 3: '+$49,999,940'}
         }

ten_percent_stocks = {"Ticker":{}, "Value": {}}

for k, v in stocks["Title"].items():
    if "10%" in v:
        ten_percent_stocks["Ticker"][k] = stocks["Ticker"][k]
        ten_percent_stocks["Value"][k] = stocks["Value"][k]
```

With dictionary comprehension you could get the same result by doing this:

```py
ten_percent_stocks = {"Ticker": {k: v for k, v in stocks["Ticker"].items() 
                                 if "10%" in stocks["Title"][k]},
                      "Value": {k: v for k, v in stocks["Value"].items()
                                if "10%" in stocks["Title"][k]}
                     }
```

But I'll find writing the actual `for` loop a bit cleaner.
The result in both cases is:

```py
{'Ticker': {0: 'AKUS', 1: 'HHC'}, 'Value': {0: '+$374,908,350', 1: '+$109,214,243'}}
```

An additional change in your origin dictionary could be, as you use always the same indices, instead of storing informations in three separate dictionaries, make use of `tuples`, that stores stocks in the order *ticker*, *title* and *value*, i.e.:

```py
stocks = {0: ('AKUS', '10%', '+$374,908,350'),
          1: ('HHC', 'Dir, 10%', '+$109,214,243'),
          2: ('IOVA', 'Dir', '+$65,000,000'),
          3: ('DDOG', 'Dir', '+$49,999,940')
         }

# Filtering stocks where title contains "10%":
ten_percent_stocks = {k: (v[0], v[2]) for k, v in stocks.items() if "10%" in v[1]}
```

Giving you the result as follows:

```py
{0: ('AKUS', '+$374,908,350'), 1: ('HHC', '+$109,214,243')}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a dictionary filled with 3 keys: "Ticker", "Title" and "Value". The ticker key contains 100 stock tickers that corresponds to the value of the purchase and title that are in the same position.

**This organization of the data makes no sense**. Your data represents 100 stock tickers; a stock ticker is a coherent thing that can be represented with a dict; therefore, the data should be a list of dicts, where each dict has the `'Ticker'`, `'Title'` and `'Value'` keys and gives that data for that stock.

So, the first step is to organize the data properly; then any further manipulation is trivial.

We know how to get the necessary data for a stock with a given ID number: we access each key, and then for each of those keys we index again with the ID. So, getting the ticker for stock 0 is just `all_stocks['Ticker'][0]` (supposing our original dict is named `all_stocks`), etc. We can easily use that sort of logic to create a dictionary for stock 0. Let's wrap that logic in a function:

```
def make_stock_dict(all_stocks, stock_id):
    return {
        'Ticker': all_stocks['Ticker'][stock_id],
        'Title': all_stocks['Title'][stock_id],
        'Value': all_stocks['Value'][stock_id]
    }
```

Now it's trivial to use a list comprehension to apply the function:

```
converted_stocks = [make_stock_dict(all_stocks, i) for i in range(100)]
```

> For example, I want to create a 10% dictionary that contains all the tickers and values of stocks where the title contained 10%.

Same idea, now that we have properly organized data: we figure out the code that tells us whether a stock qualifies, then we apply it to each stock.

```
[s for s in converted_stocks if '10%' in s['Title']]
```